# Early expiry options/deconvolution

Tags: options

Take a standard Markov setting (with assumptions as needed)

$$
dX_t = \mu(t,X_t)dt + \sigma(t,X_t) dW_t
$$

Assume, you can get the distribution (i.e. option prices) for $t_1$ (the early expiry) and $t_2$. What I am really after is what can be said about $X$ in in that interval. I was thinking we can get the distribution of $\log X_{t_2} = \log X_{t_1} + \log X_{t_2-t_1}$ via deconvolution of the characteristic functions.

Is there anything else we can say, maybe about the conditional distributions? This is probably a basic question. Would appreciate if someone could point me towards the right approach here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is a nice question. I have thought about this for a bit, but can only offer the following so far - maybe it helps the discussion.

---

Let's call the period 1 log return $x_1$, the period 2 log return $x_2$, and the joint return $y=x_1+x_2$.

If we assume independence of $x_1$ and $x_2$, we get for the characteristic function $\phi(t)$

$$
\begin{align}
\phi_y(t)&\equiv\mathrm{E}\left(e^{ity}\right)\\
&=\mathrm{E}\left(e^{it\left(x_1+x_2\right)}\right)\\
&=\mathrm{E}\left(e^{itx_1}\right)\mathrm{E}\left(e^{itx_2}\right)
\\&=\phi_{x_1}(t)\phi_{x_2}(t) \\
\Rightarrow \quad\quad\quad \phi_{x_2}(t)&=\frac{\phi_y(t)}{\phi_{x_1}(t)}\\
 \Rightarrow \quad\quad\quad f(x_2)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{-itx_2}\frac{\phi_y(t)}{\phi_{x_1}(t)}\mathrm{d}t\
\end{align}
$$

which can be performed numerically. For $X_t$ following an affine jump diffusion with possibly time dependent parameters, the characteristic function(s) can be obtained numerically.

I do not know what else we can say about the **conditional** distribution $f(x_2|x_1)$, though.

Comment: Thanks for chipping in! Not sure it will gain more traction, so I have accepted yours as the best answer. It's what I had in mind, but also don't have any idea on the conditional distribution. Numerical implementation isn't that easy if I dont got for parametric distributions (and CF), I think.

Comment: Thanks. You *could* come up with a sufficiently flexible CF in a form that‘s up to a time integral (and that is easily parallelized) but if you want to calibrate to observed option data, then of course this will become quite cumbersome.